# How to add Rows to Two Tables in One Transaction?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just starting to learn C#, and .NET. My question may be quite simple, but any help would be great.

My scenario is quite simple. I have two three tables, Student, Courses and Enrollments, defined as below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFirstProject.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Custom error message: First Name is required")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Custom error message: Last Name is required")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }  
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFirstProject.Models
{
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }

        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 5, ErrorMessage = "Number of credits must be between 0 and 5")]
        public int TotalCredits { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }    
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyFirstProject.Models
{
    public class Enrollment
    {
        public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, NullDisplayText = "No Grade")]
        public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
        //Every enrollment has at least one student and one course.
        public virtual Student student { get; set; }
        public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now if i want to add records to the Student table and Enrollment table in one database transaction, how would i go about doing that.
Let's say there are three courses in the Course table:
CourseId: 1, CourseName: Math, TotalCredits: 4
CourseId: 2, CourseName: Physics, TotalCredits: 4
CourseId: 3, CourseName: Chemistry, TotalCredits: 4

If i try to add a student, and an enrollment, how would i get the id of the student that i am adding? Psuedo code below:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.FirstName = "John";
s.LastName = "Doe";
db.Student.Add(s);
db.SaveChanges();   
Enrollment e = new Enrollment();
e.CourseId = 1;
e.StudentId = s.StudentId //I need to get the student id for the above added student. How?
db.Enrollment.Add(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is this Entity Framework, or what flavor of LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the id manually. Instead, set the relationship with your `student` property.

```
e.student = s;
```

For what it's worth, you should also use object initialization, since it makes the code much cleaner. Instead of creating a new instance and then filling the properties one by one, do it like this:

```
var s = new Student
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
};

var e = new Enrollment
{
    CourseId = 1,
    student = s
};

// this will actually add student as well since it's related
db.Enrollment.Add(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, if you're adding a new related item, you can actually combine the two object initializations:

```
var e = new Enrollment
{
    CourseId = 1,
    student = new Student
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe"
    }
};
```

Comment: This looked so promising. I've tried it, and it still doesn't work. When adding the enrollment, the StudentId still shows as 0.

Comment: It will until you've run `SaveChanges`.

Comment: That's what i thought. But after running SaveChanges as well, i don't see the enrollment record in the database.

Comment: If you added the `Enrollment` instance to the DbSet and ran `SaveChanges` without error, then it persisted it *somewhere*. Perhaps, the database you think your application is connected to isn't actually the one it's connected to.

Comment: I'm going to try and debug. I know the database is right, it adds the student records.